# How can I get only one line for output of command in powershell?

Tags: linux, powershell, command-line

In Linux I use this for select specific line:

`ip a | sed -n '3p' | xargs`

But I don't know how can I make it in Powershell.

Comment: You won't be able to get the broadcast address easily in Powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Smorkster mentioned, powershell works in objects.

you can use dot notation as shown here to access a property of an object and then use indexing

```
(Get-NetIPAddress).ipaddress[3]
```

Comment: What I exactly need is to extract a specific line from a command output

Comment: Well, like I said the output in PowerShell is not text. 
What are you trying to solve? It would be helpful to know the use case for this.
There are many ways you can filter pipeline objects

Comment: What I want is that if there is a closed port and an error is returned when the command is output, take only the last line:
with error:
Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel "Quiet" 8.8.8.8 -p 81

without error:
Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel "Quiet" 8.8.8.8 -p 53

Comment: Basically omit the error only for the output of this command, with what you have told me I have improved the command to this (Test-NetConnection 192.168.1.1 -p 81) .TcpTestSucceeded

Comment: The output from Test-NetConnection is super annoying!

Here you go:
 `Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel "Quiet" 8.8.8.8 -p 81 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 0):

Powershell works (almost exclusively) in objects. That way you can use indexing to get a certain value/output.
So you can do

```
( Get-NetIPAddress ).ToString()[3]
```

Comment: On my machine `( Get-NetIPAddress ).ToString()[3] ` just gives a single letter `t`

Comment: Okey. Wasn't sure of the output, but if you get only a characters, the output is a single string, so PS indexes the 3:d letter.

Comment: What I exactly need is to extract a specific line from a command output